# S3 plugin for munin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing issue  with *s3 curl* package installation on *aws server* . Not aware of the key-name of *s3 bucket* . But aws-acess-key, bucket-name and aws-secret-key is there with me. **Please guide me how can i get this key.**

```
Error Message :-

The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed 
using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

Run the sample using a command-line interface. For example:

./s3curl.pl --id=[aws-access-key-id] --key=[aws-secret-access-key] -- 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket-name]/[key-name]


Installation Document :-

http://www.ohardt.com/dev/munin/
```